# rails select box options default not from the array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-select

Ok,

**This creates a select box in rails.**

```
<%= select("dashboard_sub_category", "id",options_for_select( @vendor_sub_categories.collect {|p| [p.category_name, p.sub_category_id] }.unshift(["All Categories", 0]))) %>
```

When my page loads, I want an element in the select box that says,

**"All Categories"**

and I want it to be ***selected by default.***

I have used ***unshift*** like above.

### Is that a good? Any other ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I like to extract the creation of the selector options out in to maybe a before_filter, just so that the view doesn't have to do any of that code. It can just take in something like `@options` and in the future you can change how that's generated without changing the view, just the controller, as that falls under its scope. The view shouldn't do any real coding work.

Then I usually generate that like this:

```
@options = Model.all.inject(Array.new) do |sel, model|
  sel << [model.category_name, model.sub_category_id]
end
@options = [["All Categories", 0]] + @options
```

Then you can just use `@options` for your select tag.

Comment: Please see my edit. Your way is both time-efficient and readable.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize it was actually any faster ha. Well there you go! Thanks for that information!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the include blank to your select code, then in your database set the default position to 0 or All Categories so that when accessing the select menu the default value is 0/All categories.

```
{:include_blank => 'All Categories'}
```

Note sure if zI put it inside the correct parenthesis but try this

```
<%= select("dashboard_sub_category", "id",options_for_select( @vendor_sub_categories.collect {|p| [p.category_name, p.sub_category_id] }.unshift(["All Categories", 0], { :include_blank => 'All Categories' }))) %>
```

Comment: No man, include blank, just adds another "All Categories" to it.

Comment: @beck03076 yes it does but you can set it as the default value. Another solution would be to use the grouped_collection_select and set the All Categories name elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

**Dude, Your point is, move that operation to the controller, dont do it in the view.
I totally agree with that and Im so thankful for your answer.**

*I will move that to the controller and create @options, thanks.*

Now, lets talk about what I disagree with.

Are you saying?

This,

```
@options = Model.all.inject(Array.new) do |sel, model|
  sel << [model.category_name, model.sub_category_id]
end
@options = [["All Categories", 0]] + @options
```

is better than this,

```
Model.collect {|p| [p.category_name, p.sub_category_id] }.unshift(["All Categories", 0])
```

### Can I expect an explanation?

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :027 >  timing = Benchmark.measure {@options = v.sub_categories.inject(Array.new) do |sel, model|
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :028 >        sel << [model.category_name, model.sub_category_id]
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :029?>     end
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :030?>   @options = [["All Categories", 0]] + @options
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :031?>   }
 =>   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000079)



ruby-1.9.2-p290 :023 > timing = Benchmark.measure { v.sub_categories.collect {|p| [p.category_name, p.sub_category_id] }.unshift(["All Categories", 0])}
 =>   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000086)
```

Comment: Sorry I should have been more explicit, I meant that just I, personally, like to generate them that way, for no other reason than I find it easier to read.